# Query of retrieving unique users who overwrite each other

Tags: mysql

I have the following set of data :

```
id  changeType  dateTimeStamp       userName
1   insert      07/02/2015 0:15:53  john
2   update      07/02/2015 0:15:52  adriana
3   insert      07/02/2015 0:15:51  john
4   update      07/02/2015 0:15:50  john
5   update      07/01/2015 22:46:57 denise
```

I am trying to retrieve users who overwrites each other's data that made a change within 5 minutes of each other. For this particular sets of data, I should get IDs 1, 2, and 3.

I tried :

```
SELECT *
FROM tblChanges v1 
INNER JOIN tblChanges v2 
        ON v2.userName <> v1.userName 
        AND v1.dateTimeStamp <> v2.dateTimeStamp 
WHERE ABS( TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, v1.dateTimeStamp, v2.dateTimeStamp )  ) <= 5
```

This also retrieves ID=4 which I don't need. Any help?

thanks in advance.

EDIT : Output would be

```
 id  changeType   dateTimeStamp       userName
  1   insert      07/02/2015 0:15:53  john
  2   update      07/02/2015 0:15:52  adriana
  3   insert      07/02/2015 0:15:51  john
```

EDIT: here are the DDL / DML

```
CREATE TABLE `tblChanges` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `changeType` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateTimeStamp` DATETIME NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   `userName` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;

 INSERT INTO tblChanges ( id, changeType, dateTimeStamp, userName ) 
 VALUES (1, 'insert' , '2015-07-02 12:15:53', 'john' ) ;

INSERT INTO tblChanges  ( id, changeType, dateTimeStamp, userName ) 
VALUES (2, 'update' , '2015-07-02  12:15:52', 'adriana' ) ;

INSERT INTO tblChanges ( id, changeType, dateTimeStamp, userName ) 
VALUES (3, 'insert' , '2015-07-02 12:15:51', 'john' ) ;

INSERT INTO tblChanges ( id, changeType, dateTimeStamp, userName ) 
VALUES (4, 'update' , '2015-07-02  12:15:50', 'john' ) ;

INSERT INTO tblChanges ( id, changeType, dateTimeStamp, userName ) 
VALUES (5, 'update' , '2015-07-01  22:46:57', 'denise' ) ;
```

Comment: Can you give your expected output?

Comment: instead of * specify columns which is required.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so (you haven't), provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so (again you haven't really), provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Sadikhasan : Edit includes sample output and scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Your join is selecting records that occur both before and after the current record, instead of only after.

Suggest:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblChanges v1 
INNER JOIN tblChanges v2 
        ON v2.userName <> v1.userName 
        AND v2.dateTimeStamp BETWEEN v1.dateTimeStamp AND DATE_ADD(v1.dateTimeStamp, INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
```

Comment: this does not provide the desired output. I should retrieve IDs 1,2 and 3 as mentioned above.

Comment: Row 3 doesn't match the criteria - the only row affected by row 3 is row 1, which was done by the same user so it's discounted.  The three rows that are affected by others are ids 2,3,4 - and the rows that affected them are 1, 2 and 2. - both sets available in the output of my query.

Comment: sorry, the only row affected by row 3 is row 4 is what I meant.